Expression for bulk modulus exactly. It is pressure itself or change in pressure?
In my case
I considered a solid sphere of volume 1m^3 and bulk modulus is 10^5
So i calculated volume changes from 0 to 2 pascals in two different approaches
Approach 1:
B= change in pressure/(change in volume/volume)
So i went to change pressure from 0 to 1 pascal first , solving gives me volume as 1-(10^-5)m^3 and then i changed it from 1 to 2 pascals then
10^5= 2-1/(change in volume/ (1-(10^-5)))
Which gives change in volume as 10^-5 - 10^-10
Which gives me volume as 1- 2×10^-5 + 10^-10
Approach 2:
When changing pressure from 0 to 2 pascals then
Solving gives the final volume as 1- 2×10^-5
But there is difference in both methods why?

Please let me know if I am mistaken about concept
I was asked this question by my friend but I am not able to answer, why there is difference in both approaches even though the final pressure is same but I didn't see the change in force expression in Y= (Force/ area)/(change in length/ length)
This is not a homework question but I am curious why the answers are different even the pressures are same
If I think in any wrong way. Please explain where I am wrong.

Why stop at 2 steps? Why not split further into steps of 0.5 pascals, 0.1 pascals and so on? Or even better, integrate?

But in solving any problems in my book . I havent seen such approach. But, can we apply integration to longitudinal compression and expansion, too.

The formula is an approximation for small changes, so second-order terms are ignored and the two results are the same. It's the same as how by taking smaller and smaller steps, the result becomes closer and closer to the exact result, which is an integral: https://blogmedia.testbook.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/riemann-integral_1-2fdfe49b.png. But there is no need to integrate because the approximation is almost always good enough.
